# Unable to load iMessage extension on a physical device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, imessage, imessage-extension

I'm developing an iMessage app extension on an existing project. When I run it on a simulator it works correct. But when I open it on a physical device, the iMessage says "Unable to load extension" or there maybe an infinite loading icon.[image]

I've tried to hard reload the iphone and reinstall the app but it doesn't help.

Comment: Having the same issue here! Are you using SwiftUI by any chance?

Comment: I'm using react-native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more information it’s hard to tell the exact reason why this is happening.

But you definitely have some sort of exception which is unhandled. Check your logs to get an idea of where it’s originating from.

However,some people have found success uninstalling and reinstalling and have found success in this thread: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/62893